# Using Dapper and Npgsql unable to select from a list of Guids

Tags: c#, ienumerable, npgsql

Taking an example from a previous post; I am unable to query using IN and a list of Guids; I get different errors depending on what I have tried...

```cs
public class DataAccess
{
    string _connectionString = "{your connection string}";

    public async Task<IEnumerable<CustomerDto>> GetListAsync(List<Guid> customers)
    {
        const string query = @"
            SELECT Id,
                    Name
            FROM Customers
            WHERE Id IN @CustomerIdList
        ";

        using (var c = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            return await c.QueryAsync<CustomerDto>(query, new { CustomerIdList = customers.ToArray() });
        }
    }
}
```

The above fails with `42601: syntax error at or near "$1"`

I have tried various things like the below which also fails with `42601: syntax error at or near "$1"`:

```
return await c.QueryAsync<CustomerDto>(query, new { CustomerIdList = new[] { customers[ 0 ], customers[ 1 ], customers[ 2 ], customers[ 3 ] } } );
```

Can anyone help, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Fixed query due to copying example code example from another question

Comment: Perhaps I am remembering it wrong but Postgres uses LIMIT not TOP and it should go after the WHERE

Comment: IN doesn't work with parameters. However, posgresql has ANY, which is better in this case (Id = ANY(@CustomerIdList)), and does work with (array) parameters

Comment: @Steve, yeah sorry that was copy/paste error from a different question which I mentioned. Will fix

Comment: @Evk thanks, I just found it myself as well but i didnt refresh the page before I added my answer; sorry and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Found out](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/1324) that you have to use a different clause as IN does not work with an array of parameters in Postgresql which sounds like a bit of a flaw to me:

```cs
WHERE Id = ANY(@CustomerIdList)
```

Comment: It's important to understand that an array and a recordset are two very different things, hence the different constructs needed when working with them.

Comment: @ShayRojansky of course, but I do not understand why you mention that as it doesnt seem to have any relationship to the question or answer.